# Pulling text from text_area_tag on link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So right now I have a modal that pops up and it has a list of emails in it from a db query. What I want to be able to do is on a link_to being clicked, pull the information from the text_area and use it inside of my controller.

I think part of the issue might be that I have the route setup as a get right now, but I don't know if setting it up as a put or post will do anything since I am not actually saving anything to a database.

Here is the code of my form in show page:

```
<%= text_area_tag 'test_area', Query.collect(&:email).join(", "), :style => 'width:100%; height:200px;' %>    
<%= link_to 'Send Mail', admin_send_test_mail_path, :class => "btn btn-default" %>
```

Here is the route:

```
get 'send_test_mail', to: 'my_controller#send_test_mail', as: :send_test_mail
```

here is the controller:

```
def send_test_mail
    puts params[:test_area] #Doesn't output anything
    NotificationMailer.test_email_stuff.deliver
    redirect_to my_path
end
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm still a little hazy when it comes to passing params from view to controller so maybe that is where I am messing up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put this into a form and use submit_tag instead of link_to:

```
<%= form_tag send_test_mail_path do %>
  <%= text_area_tag 'test_area', Query.collect(&:email).join(", "), style: 'width:100%; height:200px;' %>    
  <%= submit_tag 'Send Mail', class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

---

If you realy want to use link_to then you could achieve this using js:

```
<%= form_tag send_test_mail_path do %>
  <%= text_area_tag 'test_area', Query.collect(&:email).join(", "), style: 'width:100%; height:200px;' %>    
  <%= link_to 'Send Mail', '#', class: "btn btn-default", onclick: "$(this).closest('form').submit()" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This works (after changing my route to post instead of get). My question if you don't mind, is why wouldn't the link_to work? It seems like it is just calling the route the same way.

Comment: @Matthew, yes you are right that it calls the same route but it doesn't "know" what to do with form fields. Link tag doesn't trigger form submition by default. Link tag main purpose is to move user to another page (a GET request) and not to submit a form data (mostly a POST request). But as you see we can force it to do what we want via js. I'd advise you to read more about simple html forms outside of rails scope.

Comment: I appreciate you getting back with me. That makes sense. I will definitely do more research on forms and how they handle data